# Multiply the Sum of one Cell if another cell shows value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros

I've added a hidden cell (T259) which calculates 10% of Cell U78 if "Mortar Joint" is selected in the Sales Agreement sheet. I want to add a function in cell U78 to add the value of T259. I am getting "too many arguments error".

This is the formula that returns the error. 
=IF(T74="1/2Dry Stack",0.1,IF(T74="DryMortar Joint",-0.1,0,IF('Sales Agreement'!G23="Mortar Joint w/ Standard Grey",0.1,0)))

Sorry I moved ahead without updating the question, since this problem is time sensitive. [UPDATE]

Basically in the screenshot you'll see cell U78, I'd like that to **either add or subtract an additional 10% based on the value of cell G23 in the Sales Agreement sheet.** The formula I am trying is in the screen shot. Any help?

Here is where you'll see the formula I am trying to add 10%. I came up with the idea to put it on a different cell since I kept getting the "too many arguments" error and have it somehow send the sum back to cell U78 where I need it.

Here is where you'll see the original formula in cell U78 subtracting 10%.

[image]

This is the drop down list I need the formula to be based on.

[image]

Comment: Your current formula looks at T74 for a string, but there is nothing in T74? Can you update your question with a simple example of what you want? EG: 'I need cell U78 on sheet Work Order Calculator to say 0.1 if cell G23 on Sales Agreement contains ABC, or -0.1 if G23 on Sales Agreement contains XYZ'

Comment: Your question is a bit hard to follow. It is not clear what your end goal is. Are you trying to sum the value in `V78` either +10% or -10% based on the value in `T74` (I noticed there is a hidden row)? The formula you refer to is using `T74`, not `G23` in the `Sales Agreement` sheet. Does `T74` get its value from the other sheet? At this point it shows a `0`, not the value of the dropdown in `G23`?

Comment: Correct Charlie, I'm just adding to an original formula. Cell U78 is currently based on the value in T74 and T74 gets it's value from another sheet. I'd just like to add in cell U78 =IF cell G23 in Sales Agreement shows a specific value from the drop down list, i.e: dry stack, to add 10% of the original value.

Comment: Sorry, but your update makes it even less clear. That has nothing to do with what you explained initially. I think you are trying to solve many things at once which causes it to be unclear. Please edit this question to be specific to the question you are asking.

Comment: I see how it is unclear. I've fumbled the question. I'll rephrase.

Comment: Sorry for the mix up. If I need to explain further please let me know.

Comment: =IF(T74="1/2Dry Stack",0.1,IF(T74="DryMortar Joint",-0.1,0,IF('Sales Agreement'!G23="Mortar Joint w/ Standard Grey",0.1,0)))

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, your formula does have too many arguments:

=IF(T74="1/2Dry Stack",0.1,IF(T74="DryMortar Joint",-0.1,***0***,IF('Sales Agreement'!G23="Mortar Joint w/ Standard Grey",0.1,0)))

I believe the actual formula you want is:

`=IF(T74="1/2Dry Stack",0.1,IF(T74="DryMortar Joint",-0.1,IF('Sales Agreement'!G23="Mortar Joint w/ Standard Grey",0.1,0)))`

Edit: After further comment I believe you want:

`=IF(T74="1/2Dry Stack",1.1,IF(T74="DryMortar Joint",0.9,IF('Sales Agreement'!G23="Mortar Joint w/ Standard Grey",1.1,1)))*VALUE`

VALUE being the amount/cell you want to potentially add or remove 10% to.

Honestly I'm still not entirely sure where you want to put your result, but using 1, 1.1 and 0.9 you can simply multiply it against the number to get +10%, -10% or the original figure.

Comment: OOOOOHHHH!!! So instead of adding the "if false=0" just begin the new IF function! Wow. Thank you once again Jonno

Comment: Now does this multiply my value by 0.1? Adding 10%?  i.e if the value become 100 it becomes 110?

Comment: This simply gives 0.1, 0 or -0.1. You would probably be better off using 1.1, 1.0 or 0.9, then you can multiply that by your value.

Comment: @ElonDaly Just updated my answer to show what you can use to do this.

Comment: If I wanted it to multiply in the function should I use SUMPRODUCT function? i.e =IF(T74="1/2Dry Stack",0.1,IF(T74="DryMortar Joint",-0.1,SUMPRODUCT(IF('Sales Agreement'!G23="Mortar Joint w/ Standard Grey",*0.1,0)))

Comment: @ElonDaly Sorry I'm still confused. Should U78 contain your finished amount? (Eg, if the amount is 100, and T74 is 1/2DryStack, should U78 contain 0.1, or 110?)

Comment: U78 should contain 0.1 and carry down the 110 to V91. I'm finding holes as I continue to learn and talk to you guys.